# Excel workbook closing but worksheet staying active?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have this script that I had running, but modified to sort data into different sheets based on an input box.  It works, and does everything I want it to, but now, every time I run it, a new instance of Excel runs in the background.  As far as I can tell(and I don't really know much about this sort of thing), is that somehow the workbook is closing, but the worksheet is staying active. I've been looking up stuff and reading for hours trying to figure this out, am I at least heading in the right direction??  This is a basic script inserted into a PC DMIS program(outside of Excel).  I have the changes I made to achieve the sorting process(2 paragraphs) marked with "worksheet input":

```
Sub Main 


'xl Declarations
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbooks As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim count As Integer
Dim xlWorksheets As String 
Dim xlWorksheet As String 

'pcdlrn declarations And Open ppg
Dim App As Object
Set App = CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")
Dim Part As Object
Set Part = App.ActivePartProgram
Dim Cmds As Object
Set Cmds = Part.Commands
Dim Cmd As Object
Dim DCmd As Object
Dim DcmdID As Object
Dim fs As Object 
Dim DimID As String 
Dim ReportDim As String
Dim CheckDim As String 

Dim Cavity As String                                              ‘start worksheet input 1
Dim myValue As String 
Dim message, title, defaultValue As String 
message = "Cavity" 
title = "cavity" 
defaultValue = "1" 
myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)
If myValue = "" Then myValue = defaultValue       ‘end worksheet input 1

'Check To see If results file exists
FilePath = "C:\Excel PC DMIS\3K170 B2A\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
ResFileExists = fs.fileexists(FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls")

'Open Excel And Base form
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWorkbooks = xlapp.Workbooks
If ResFileExists = False Then
    TempFilename = FilePath & "Loop Template.xls"
Else
    TempFilename = FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls"
End If

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(TempFilename)
Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set xlsheets = xlworkbook.worksheets                   ‘start worksheet input 2

'Set xlWorksheets = xlapp.Worksheet
'Set xlWorksheets = xlapp.Worksheets
Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each sh In xlworkbook.worksheets
     If sh.Name = myValue Then flg = True: Exit For 
Next

If flg = False Then 
   xlsheets.Add.Name = myValue
End If

Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(myValue)       ‘end worksheet input 2


If ResFileExists = False Then
    RCount=6
    CCount=3
    xlSheet.Range("B1").Value = Part.PartName
    xlSheet.Range("A6").Value = Date() & " " & Time()
    xlSheet.Range("B6").Value = "Inspector Name"
    For Each Cmd In Cmds
        'Eliminate DATDEF's
        If Cmd.Type <> 1299 Then
            'Do Dimensions
            If Cmd.IsDimension Then
                If Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_START_LOCATION Or Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION Then
                    Set DcmdID = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                      DimID = DcmdID.ID
                      ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                End If
                If Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_START_LOCATION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_END_LOCATION And _
                    Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_END_POSITION Then
                    Set DCmd = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                    CheckDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                    If CheckDim <> "" Then
                            ReportDim = CheckDim
                    End If
                    If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        If DCmd.ID = "" Then
                                xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DimID & "."& DCmd.AxisLetter
                        Else
                                xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "M"
                        End If
                                xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                'Measured Or Deviation With check For True Position
                    If DCmd.AxisLetter <> "TP" Then
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Measured
                Else
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Deviation
                End If
                                'Add Min/Max For Profile dimensions
                                If Cmd.Type = 1118 Or Cmd.Type = 1105 Then
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "Max"
                                  xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                  xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Max
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "Min"
                                  xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                  xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Min
                                End If
                                CCount=CCount+1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            'Do GDT
            If Cmd.Type = 184 Then
                  ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                  If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (ID, 0) & "." & "FCF"
                        xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_PLUSTOL, 1)
                        xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_DEV, 1)
                        CCount=CCount+1
                  End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cmd


Else

'Find first Open column.
RCount=6
Found=0
Do Until Found = 1
RCount = RCount + 1
If xlSheet.Cells(RCount,1).Value = "" Then
Found=1
End If
Loop

xlSheet.Cells(RCount,1).Value = Date() & " " & Time()
xlSheet.Cells(RCount,2).Value= "Inspector Name"

'Fill In measured data
CCount = 3
    For Each Cmd In Cmds
        'Eliminate DATDEF's
        If Cmd.Type <> 1299 Then
            'Do Dimensions
            If Cmd.IsDimension Then
                If Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_START_LOCATION Or Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION Then
                    Set DcmdID = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                      DimID = DcmdID.ID
                      ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                End If
                If Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_START_LOCATION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_END_LOCATION And _
                    Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_END_POSITION Then
                    Set DCmd = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                    CheckDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                    If CheckDim <> "" Then
                            ReportDim = CheckDim
                    End If
                    If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                                'Measured Or Deviation With check For True Position
                            If DCmd.AxisLetter <> "TP" Then
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Measured
                Else
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Deviation
                End If
                                'Add Min/Max For Profile dimensions
                                If Cmd.Type = 1118 Or Cmd.Type = 1105 Then
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Max
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Min
                                End If
                       Ccount=Ccount+1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            'Do GDT
            If Cmd.Type = 184 Then
                  ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                  If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (ID, 0) & "." & "FCF"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_PLUSTOL, 1)
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_DEV, 1)
                        CCount=CCount+1
                  End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cmd
End If


'Save And Cleanup
Set xlSheet = Nothing 
SaveName = FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls"
If ResFileExists = False Then
xlWorkBook.SaveAs SaveName
Else
xlWorkBook.Save
End If
xlWorkbook.Close
Set xlWorkbook = Nothing 
xlWorkbooks.Close 
Set xlWorkbooks = Nothing 
xlApp.Quit 
Set xlApp = Nothing

LabelEnd:

End Sub
```

Comment: utter long short but you have the line `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` twice. Maybe remove one and try again?

Comment: Yeah, that was already pointed out and fixed, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Since ...

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

will create a new instance of Excel, you can first check to see if an Excel instance has already been established with the following code.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject("","Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'No instance exists, create one
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
```

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I have been busy with other projects, and am just now getting back to this.  I tried using the code you gave me, but had to modify the second line to Set xlApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application") because I was getting a syntax error, and added "Then" after <> 0.  It runs through with no errors, but it is not opening Excel at all.

Comment: updated the code. This code will (should) open an excel instance, but it won't be visible. Do you want it to be visible?

Comment: That's exactly what I have now, but for some reason, it is not doing the "create object".  It is not writing to Excel at all for some reason

Comment: If the create object code is not hit, that means an instance of excel is already open, and the `GetObject` would have returned an Excel instance for you. Whether `xlApp` has a newly created Excel instance, or grabs an existing one, it should provide you with an instance from which you can open your workbook and edit it.